# FMUchecker - [FATAL][FMICAPI] Could not load the DLL:

Tags: dll, simulation, simulink, c-api

**Hello,
I exported a simulink model as a FMU. When I run the FMU checker on it, I get the following two (fatal) errors:**

[FATAL][FMICAPI] Could not load the DLL: Eine DLL-Initialisierungsroutine ist fehlgeschlagen.
[FATAL][FMUCHK] Could not create the DLL loading mechanism(C-API) for CoSimulation.

**When I try to run the FMU in python, using the fmpy library, I get the following error (where "varmod_tsst.fmu" is my FMU):**

Exception: Failed to load shared library C:\Users\jakob\AppData\Local\Temp\tmphvispyid\binaries\win64\varmod_tsst.dll. Could not find module 'C:\Users\jakob\AppData\Local\Temp\tmphvispyid\binaries\win64\varmod_tsst.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.

**When exporting a minimal FMU (constant input results in output), I don't get any errors.
So I think this might have something to do with the simscape blocks in my original simulink model, or some other blocks.
Furthermore, the FMUchecker doesn't return any errors, if I use a fixed-step solver.**

Answer (score -1):

The problem was that I had to run the FMU from the same folder in which matlab.exe lies.
So it seems like one would need to specify some dependency if the FMU is stored in another folder. But I don't know if this works, yet.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).